# Online research projects

Tags: research-process, mathematics, research-undergraduate, physics, research-topic

Are there any research projects in mathematics,data science etc undergraduate students can participate online? Have seen something like that?
Well, I googled it and found something,but I need more information.

Comment: What do you mean by "participate"? What are you prepared to contribute? How long for? What do you want at the end of your time or the end of the project?

Comment: I  want to improve my research skills.I don't have any straight answer for these questions.

Comment: Please explain what you found by googling, so that there is no duplication of effort.

Answer (score 0):

One option I can think of is in engaging in writing open source software related to such fields. You can gather experience in setting up goals and realizing them and you will work together with academics, students and hobby enthusiasts in the open source community.

A scientific/research project is often not very different to a open source software project with a experienced PI/group leader and PhD students, undergraduate students.

Github or scicomp/datascience/stats.stackexchange could be a good starting point or this [citizen science register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_citizen_science_projects).